# Perform sudo with different password?

Tags: sudo, password, root

Can I perform 'sudo' actions with different password other than my login password?

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not.

`sudo` basically enables one to impersonate other user (by default root) by providing the credential for the user who is running the `sudo` command (given the user running `sudo` is in the `sudoers` file with sufficient privilege).

At most, you can run specific commands with `NOPASSWD` parameter so that those commands while running with `sudo` won't require your password but in all other cases you can not use any other password rather than your account's one.